# Transforming a scala list based on condition

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a sorted list of tuples (sorted by last element which is linenumber)

```
val x = List(
            ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1443),
            ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1492),
            ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1510),
            ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1528),
            ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1551),
            ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1555),
            ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1602),
            ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1614)
          )
```

I need to transform this into

```
 ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1443),
 ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1528),
 ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1551),
 ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1555),
 ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1602),
 ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1614)
```

Two elements are removed based on the condition of iterating the list and only picking the previous EXIT upon encountering the next ENTER in the list

Finally need to transform this into a tripe

```
("CS", 1443, 1528)
("CS", 1551, 1555)
("CS", 1602, 1614)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.foldLeft` is the way to go which is basically an accumulator pattern. You need to know creating a new list on top of existing list without mutating the existing(which is `:+`), also updating data using `.copy`

```
val data = List(
  ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1443),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1492),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1510),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1528),
  ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1551),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1555),
  ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1602),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1614)
)

val enterExits =
  data.foldLeft((List.empty[(String, Int)], Option.empty[(String, Int)])) {
    case ((state, previousSignal), signal) =>
      if (previousSignal.exists(_._1.contains("EXIT")) && signal._1.contains("EXIT")) {
        (state.dropRight(1) :+ signal, Some(signal))
      } else {
        (state :+ signal, Some(signal))
      }
  }

val triple =
  enterExits._1
    .foldLeft(
      (List.empty[(String, Int, Int)], Option.empty[(String, Int, Int)])) {
      case ((state, accSignal), signal) =>
        if (signal._1.contains("ENTER")) {
          (state, Some(("CS", signal._2, 0)))
        } else {
          val enterExt = accSignal.map(elem => elem.copy(_3 = signal._2))
          (state :+ enterExt.get, Option.empty)
        }
    }._1

triple.foreach { ee =>
  println(ee)
}
```

**output:**

```
(CS,1443,1528)
(CS,1551,1555)
(CS,1602,1614)
```

Note: The answer above assumes there will always be Equivalent `Exit` for each `Enter`.

running code at: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/3670tsL0Qf683QFAQ9nLIQ

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `foldLeft` with a Tuple-type accumulator carrying the current string element over for equality check in the next iteration, followed by a `grouped` for the final transformation:

```
val list = List(
  ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1443),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1492),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1510),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1528),
  ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1551),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1555),
  ("taskENTER_CRITICAL", 1602),
  ("taskEXIT_CRITICAL", 1614)
)

val list2 = list.foldLeft( (List[(String, Int)](), "") ){
  case ((l, sp), (s, i)) => s match {
    case "taskENTER_CRITICAL" => ((s, i) :: l, s)
    case "taskEXIT_CRITICAL" if s == sp => ((s, i) :: l.tail, s)
    case _ => ((s, i) :: l, s)
  }
}._1.reverse
// list2: List[(String, Int)] = List(
//   (taskENTER_CRITICAL,1443), (taskEXIT_CRITICAL,1528),
//   (taskENTER_CRITICAL,1551), (taskEXIT_CRITICAL,1555),
//   (taskENTER_CRITICAL,1602), (taskEXIT_CRITICAL,1614)
// )

list2.grouped(2).collect{ case List(a, b) => ("CS", a._2, b._2) }.toList
// res2: List[(String, Int, Int)] = List((CS,1443,1528), (CS,1551,1555), (CS,1602,1614))
```

Note that reversal of list elements is needed after `foldLeft` since the list is assembled in reverse order with `::` and `tail` for performance at scale.